# How to convert current time to CET in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have seen couple of questions on the same, but which I'm facing the issue is not addressed anywhere so that only asking again.
I am trying to convert current time to CET time so initially i had implemented like this

```js
component.ts

public currentDate;
ngOnInit(){
this.currentDate = new Date();
}


component.html

TIME: {{currentDate | date:'h:mm a':'+0100'}}
```

With above snippet initially it was matching fine with CET time, but now getting one hour difference. And i found in docs like Central European Time CET alternates between UTC+1 (standard time) and UTC+2 (when daylight saving time (DST) is observed).
All countries in the CET time zone observe DST (UTC+2) from 02:00 am on the last Sunday of March until 03:00 am on the last Sunday of October.
So based on this from last Sunday of march to last Sunday of October supposed to add +2hrs..And tried the same and now matching the same with CET.
But how can we handle this dynamically, or any other approach to convert current time to CET, Instead of changing +1hr some time and +2hr some time period.
Thanks in advance.